# GAM Deploy tool. No se puede conectar al server Mysql

Tags: genexus15

Estoy trabajando con la versión GAM 3.0.6 y del Deploy Tools 10.3.14.114530 tratando de ejecutar cualquiera de las opciones del Deploy Tools. Al conectarme con la base de datos Mysql me da el siguiente error:

> the server specified was not found or was not accesible

Trabajando con Gx (15.0.126726 U12) no tengo problemas para la especificación pero cuando ejecuto: Tools/GAM/Create Deploy File me da el error:

> GAM Metadata Not Found. Cannot Create the deployment package. Try Creating GAM Tables first.

En el GX el conector tiene las siguientes propiedades:

> JDBC Drive: mySQL JDBC Driver (Type 4).
>
> Use custom JDBC URl: false

Cuando ejecuto el GAM Deploy tool uso:

> ```
> Server host: Localhost (he usado la ip de la maquina)
> Server port: 3307 (no es el estandar)
> Database name: la base de datos del GAM
> Usuario: root y su contraseña.
> ```

Con estas credenciales siempre me he conectado a la base de datos, es la primera vez que estoy tratando de conectarme por medio del GAM Deploy tool.

Está claro que es un problema con la conexión y no tengo idea cómo se conecta la herramienta y porque pasa que gx puede especificar y por lo tanto se conecta pero el GAM no.

Gracias desde ya por la ayuda.